# how to use maven artifacts from azure devops in scala sbt

Tags: scala, azure, azure-devops, sbt, azure-artifacts

I am successfully able to publish by Scala SBT project to Azure DevOps artifacts. However, when I am trying to setup another project to consume the JAR from this feed (as a managed dependency), SBT is unable to resolve that repository.

```
organization := "com.contoso"
name := "datapipeline-samples"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.constoso" %% "datapipeline-framework" % "2.5.1200-zmaster.139",  
  )

resolvers += Resolver.url("https://pkgsprodwus21.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", url("https://accountName.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/feed-name/maven/v1"))
credentials += Credentials("https://pkgsprodwus21.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", "accountName.pkgs.visualstudio.com", "accountName", "personal-access-token")
```

Comment: Have you checked if configuring the feed using [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/maven/pom-and-settings?view=azure-devops) instead of using code, can it work?

Comment: @rohit21agarwal If you found a solution, could you please let me know? Am stuck with the same issue.

Comment: How where you able to publish the JAR artifacts with SBT onto Azure DevOps?
I have added the repository and credentials, like I would do with Maven Central or Nexus, but it does not work (there is some authentication failure)